# AspectJ java 13 support?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, java-13

Recently upgraded a large project from Java 11 to 13.  I am using AspectJ for logging purposes and I am now getting this error on startup :

```
AspectJ Internal Error: unable to add stackmap attributes. Unsupported class file major version 57
```

Looks clear as day that Java 13 is not supported and looking at the AspectJ site they mention Java 12 support added in version 1.9.3 but as of the latest one, 1.9.4, still no mention of Java 13 support.

Any idea if there is a way around this or if the project will be updated again soon?  The last release was in May...

***UPDATE***

As requested, here are my dependency declarations :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And here are my Java Agent declarations :

```
-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar -javaagent:lib/spring-instrument-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ask at the soure of `AspectJ`? 
https://www.eclipse.org/org/foundation/contact.php

Comment: Upgrading large projects to the bleeding edge, then wondering when things break?

Comment: @Kayaman right?  haha no worries it's a personal project of mine and i figured i would upgrade java version at the same time as spring boot 2.2 since it's officially compatible now.  Again it's just for logging so worst case i'll just turn it off for now.

Comment: Since you have Spring Boot, note that Spring in general announced support for 13 only since yet-unreleased version 5.2.

Comment: 5.2.0 is released in GA from what i can tell from the Spring Boot 2.2 release notes and Maven central

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Spring boot `2.2.0` is already GA and [extends support to Java-14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58357113/1746118), that included 5.2.0 from their release candidates itself.

Comment: @Naman, that means they must've solved this problem, since they also depend on AJ. So the issue should be solved by upgrading, but OP also says he upgraded to 2.2.0 and still has it(?).

Comment: Well, yeah which brings me to the question @Martin can you share the dependency for `aspectJ` that you are using explicitly? (if) plugin as well?

Comment: updated original post

Comment: 1.9.5 dropped a few days ago.  Still getting the same error : AspectJ Internal Error: unable to add stackmap attributes. Unsupported class file major version 57

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AspectJ 1.9.5 just dropped with official Java 13 support.  Spring Boot 2.2.1 still has the 1.9.4 dependency (will probably be updated in 2.2.2) so for now you have to specify an override version in the POM.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```

Comment: For Java 17  AspectJ 1.9.8