# Could not compile settings.gradle when trying to compile android from commang line

Tags: android-studio, gradle, command-line

I installed the latest version of android SDK+Android studio but would like to compile my program from command line

I am following the tutorial here:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/10/basic-android-without-an-ide

I have reached the stage where I have intialized a folder with gradle, but have not added added java code yet (just above [this location](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/10/basic-android-without-an-ide#write-the-java-application) in the linked blog). The blog says that at this point running `gradlew build` should not give me any errors, but I am getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\gradletest\settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\gradletest\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:184)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:152)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:273)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:254)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:192)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:172)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:128)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveNonArrayType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:72)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode(MemberSignatureParser.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers(DecompiledClassNode.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(DecompiledClassNode.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:912)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.tryFindPossibleMethod(ClassNode.java:1280)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:252)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:88)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:128)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1099)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitClass(StaticImportVisitor.java:82)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:717)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1095)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:649)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:627)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:604)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:390)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:89)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:330)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:325)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:133)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:93)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler$2.run(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:151)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:132)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:175)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:155)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:98)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:85)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:207)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:197)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:142)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:78)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:94)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:118)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$RemapBuildScriptsAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:421)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$RemapBuildScriptsAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:390)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:175)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:155)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:98)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:85)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:207)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:197)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:142)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:78)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:94)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:118)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:105)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.getOrCompile(CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.java:49)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.java:50)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:50)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:37)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:104)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:45)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$LoadBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:277)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.loadSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:202)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:147)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Basically it says the error is in settings.gradle. The settings.gradle file is given below:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * The settings file is used to specify which projects to include in your build.
 *
 * Detailed information about configuring a multi-project build in Gradle can be found
 * in the user manual at https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
 */

// rootProject.name = 'gradletest'
include ':app'
```

The blog just says I need `include ':app'` in this file, and I haven't added the java code yet. How can I fix this error? Is it impossible to compile from command line if I have installed the whole android studio set (android studio+sdk+gradle)? Since I've already got it, I want to avoid installing SDK+gradle separately, as I don't want them messing up compiler path settings for the Android Studio install, but even with Android Studio installed it should still be possible to do things from command line shouldn't it?

Gradle and SDK location:

```
C:\Users\HP\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx\gradle-5.4.1\bin  

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

--- EDIT:
Solved by using an older version of Java

Comment: can you add which java version, gradle wrapper(if it is part of project, from OP: 5.4.1) or gradle version you are using?

Comment: It's java 13, that's why its not working with my gradle. Supposedly works with gradle 6 but I'm facing other errors in my setup so haven't been able to confirm it

Comment: @dkb gradle is the one installed by android studio so its 5.something

Comment: @dkb incidentally do you know if its possible to download and update sdk packages without opening android studio? Google seems to have got rid of sdk manger.exe and my computer is too slow to run AS

Comment: Check once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624755/2987755, also: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

Comment: @dkb that sdkmanager is the problem for me, may be I wasn't using it correctly, but typing simply 'sdkmanager' gives be some java exception error. May be it's not compatible with java 13 either. Is it worth downgrading Java and trying again, or is it some other problem and I should continue troubleshooting?

Comment: yes, agreed, downgrade to java-8 and check, it should work fine. Checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482204/2987755

Comment: @dkb I see.Thanks a lot. I'll save myself the trouble and just downgrade java instead of pulling my hair out on this.

Comment: @dkb hi just one question, I am trying to download jdk 8 but it looks like they've made it deliberately slow (I downloaded jdk 13 in about 20 minutes or so just few weeks ago, jdk 8 download is showing me it will take hours). I've also seen there is an open JDK. is open jdk 8 same as oracle's jdk 8, by which I mean will I be able to seamlessly able to use my android tools if I install open jdk, or will it need it's own configurations?

Comment: There is no change in oracle java-8 and OpenJDK-8, though there are differences in 11, refer: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/97eff450e9edbd7d006deb35f28e3fd4#changes-in-gc-options